# Unable to define + generically?

Tags: generics, methods, operator-overloading, factor-lang

I'm following [Andrea Ferretti's tutorial](https://andreaferretti.github.io/factor-tutorial/#the-object-system-and-protocols) and am trying to define `+` for my own type.

My tuple is:

```
TUPLE: myBox a ;
```

If I create my own generic word

```
GENERIC: my+ ( a b -- c ) 
M: myBox my+ a>> swap a>> swap + myBox boa ;
```

then I can use it to add to add the contents of two `myBox`es together

```
6 myBox boa 7 myBox boa my+
```

which outputs

```
--- Data stack:
T{ myBox f 13 }
```

However, if try to define `+` itself for `myBox` with:

```
M: myBox + a>> swap a>> swap + myBox boa ;
```

then, when I try to use it:

```
6 myBox boa 7 myBox boa +
```

I get the error:

```
No suitable arithmetic method
"left" T{ myBox f 6 }
"right" T{ myBox f 7 }
"generic" +
```

If I go to the help page for `+` I even see my definition listed amongst the others (ie `bignum`, `complex`, `fixnum`, `float`, and `ratio`).

How can I define the generic  word `+` for my own tuple?

Comment: Yes, your method is defined but not called. The problem is that '+' is a "math-combination", which uses a different dispatch. Math combinations only work on number classes. I don't remember if there's a (nice) way to extend them to work on tuple classes, or make your tuple class part of the number classes; meanwhile I thought I could comment on the why.

Comment: PS: you can define your method on class 'object' as a workaround. It's messy and ugly, but it will get called as expected.